# Ubuntu server won't boot after reboot on google cloud console

Tags: google-compute-engine

Ubuntu server won't boot after reboot on google cloud console. After rebooting, I noticed that there is 0 disk space, but I can not expand it since the server is starting (((Error in the screenshot. Please help
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v0T45.png)

---

I created a new snapshot of the disk of this VM, and created a VM from this snapshot, but the errors are the same

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the `hwmatch` module is missing, which is causing issues with the GRUB at boot time.

In this [link](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/grub2-signed/+bug/1840560) you can find several workarounds and a better grasp on `hwmatch` file and the issue taking place.

*NOTE: This link contains information which has not been endorsed by Google.*